# how to find out a div is inside window in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

when I click on Id one div is coming. But I want to check if the div is exceeding the window then the div must hide.
[image]
Here is the sample code I have tried.

```
const User= () =>{
   
    const openRequestDetails=(event,reqId)=>{
    var clkPosTop= Math.floor(event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top());
    var popup= document.getElementById('rId');
    var popupHt= popup.offsetHeight;
    if(clkPosTop > popupHt){
        popup.style.top=clkPosTop+"px";
document.getElementById('rId').style.display="block";
        }
     }
       return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>First name</td>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                </tr>
            {
                user.map((key, i)=>(
                    <tr>
                        <td onClick={(e) => openRequestDetails(e,i)}>{i}</td>
                        <td>{key.first_name}</td>
                        <td>{key.last_name}</td>
                        <td>{key.email}</td>
                        <td>{key.gender}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))
            }
            </table>
            <div id="rId" />
        </>
    )
}

export default User;
```

I am displaying the div is exact same row where I click. But when I click on the last IDs the div is exceeding the size of the window. So I want to check if the div is exceeding the windows then the display should hide.
`I just want to check when I click on id's if the div is exceeding the windows then I should not display that div otherwise it should display.`

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Here is the sample CSS file.
div#rId{
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 34px;
    width: 35%;
position:fixed;
  left:28px;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

2. Can anyone know how to solve this problem.

   ```
    We can write simple javascript code inside the function. can anyone help me to solve this problem?
   ```

Comment: if paragraph is exceeding window, you want to remove that line itself or just need to hide overlapped text?

Comment: In the refered image, you can see a green color div. That div is exceeding the window. if that div is exceeding then that should not come anymore.

Comment: you can handle using character limit in that case.

Comment: can you update my code on how to do it? I have tried many more different approaches. But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at how it's decided whether to show the pop up or not:

Here's the code where the test is made:

```
    const openRequestDetails=(event,reqId)=>{
    var clkPosTop= Math.floor(event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top());
    var popup= document.getElementById('rId');
    var popupHt= popup.offsetHeight;
    if(clkPosTop > popupHt){ //This is almost always true as popupHt is small
        popup.style.top=clkPosTop+"px";
document.getElementById('rId').style.display="block";
        }
```

What you need to do is test whether the popup when placed with its top the same as the td's top will have its bottom below the bottom of the viewport.

The bottom of the popup will be at: `clkPosTop + popupHt`

The bottom of the viewport is at `window.innerHeight`

So the test should be

```
if ( (clkPosTop + popupHt) < window.innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think your problem can resolve use only css.
But, this can change depending on what you want to do.
If your problem is only window... use `@media`, then, ok, go to css.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  @media (min-width:1024px) {
    max-width: 1024px;
  }
}
```

Ok, we delimit width of our div, but many things to happen now, then
`rId` maybe disturb our configuration, then, we need make this element responsive too.

```css
td {
  display: inline-flex; // or display: inline-grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div#rId {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  background-color: cyan;
  height: 34px;
  width: 35%;
  position:fixed;
  left:28px;
}
```

ok, I think this resolve this issue.
But, this javascript code... I don't believe i need position css with javascrip to open modal, comment if this helpfull. ;D